# Sort pandas DataFrame columns first based on year descending and then months ascending

Tags: python, pandas

I have dataframe having column names something like below:

['GUD', 'ClientName', 'Account', 'C2', 'CalcTypeKey', 'Jan-19', 'Feb-19',
'Mar-19', 'Apr-19', 'May-19', 'Jun-19', 'Jul-19', 'Aug-19', 'Sep-19',
'Oct-19', 'Nov-19', 'Dec-19', 'Jan-20', 'Feb-20', 'Mar-20', 'Apr-20',
'May-20', 'Jun-20', 'Jul-20', 'Aug-20', 'Sep-20', 'Oct-20', 'Jan-19',
'Feb-19', 'Mar-19', 'Apr-19', 'May-19', 'Jun-19', 'Jul-19', 'Aug-19',
'Sep-19', 'Oct-19', 'Nov-19', 'Dec-19', 'Jan-20', 'Feb-20', 'Mar-20',
'Apr-20', 'May-20', 'Jun-20', 'Jul-20', 'Aug-20', 'Sep-20', 'Oct-20']

I want it to ordered like below:
['GUD', 'ClientName', 'Account', 'C2', 'CalcTypeKey', 'Jan-20', 'Feb-20',
'Mar-20', 'Apr-20','May-20', 'Jun-20', 'Jul-20', 'Aug-20', 'Sep-20',
'Oct-20','Jan-19', 'Feb-19','Mar-19', 'Apr-19', 'May-19', 'Jun-19',
'Jul-19', 'Aug-19', 'Sep-19','Oct-19', 'Nov-19', 'Dec-19', 'Jan-20',
'Feb-20', 'Mar-20','Apr-20', 'May-20', 'Jun-20', 'Jul-20', 'Aug-20',
'Sep-20', 'Oct-20','Jan-19','Feb-19', 'Mar-19', 'Apr-19', 'May-19',
'Jun-19', 'Jul-19', 'Aug-19','Sep-19', 'Oct-19', 'Nov-19', 'Dec-19']

Comment: So, what's your code?

Answer (score 0):

You can convert to datetime, transform the values as needed and then [`argsort`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argsort.html) the columns:

```
import pandas as pd

cols = ['GUD', 'ClientName', 'Account', 'C2', 'CalcTypeKey', 'Jan-19', 'Feb-19', 'Mar-19', 'Apr-19', 'May-19', 'Jun-19', 'Jul-19', 'Aug-19', 'Sep-19', 'Oct-19', 'Nov-19', 'Dec-19', 'Jan-20', 'Feb-20', 'Mar-20', 'Apr-20', 'May-20', 'Jun-20', 'Jul-20', 'Aug-20', 'Sep-20', 'Oct-20']
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=cols)

x = pd.to_datetime(cols[5:], format='%b-%y')
df = df.iloc[:, list(range(5)) + (((3000-x.year)*100 + x.month).to_numpy().argsort()+5).tolist()]
```

Result:

```
Columns: [GUD, ClientName, Account, C2, CalcTypeKey, Jan-20, Feb-20, Mar-20, Apr-20, May-20, Jun-20, Jul-20, Aug-20, Sep-20, Oct-20, Jan-19, Feb-19, Mar-19, Apr-19, May-19, Jun-19, Jul-19, Aug-19, Sep-19, Oct-19, Nov-19, Dec-19]
```

Note that you have multiple columns with same names in your example which obviously can't be meaningfully sorted. That's why I removed them.